# Azure DevOps Get Results with details REST API does not always return associated bugs

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops-rest-api

The Azure DevOps Get Results REST API [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) includes an option to return linked work items with the associatedBugs property. In my test result analysis, I have created bugs from the Azure DevOps UI for a particular test failure in Release pipeline (could do the same for build pipeline test as well). I don't see a consistent behavior of the API returning all the linked bugs. For example: in the Azure DevOps UI, I see 2 bugs listed but when I use the above API, I get nothing.

Can somebody explain the actual behavior of the API? I want to capture this information to associate an custom Work Item type with the all the test runs that were executed for that work item type and the related bugs found.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to list the linked Bug work items, you can use the parameter '**`detailsToInclude`**' and set its value to be '**`workItems`**'.

By default, the parameter '**`detailsToInclude`**' is set to '**`none`**' (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#uri-parameters)). If you want to always expand the details of the linked work items in the response body of this API, you can explicitly set the value to '**`workItems`**'.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=workItems&api-version=6.0
```

[image]

You also can set multiple comma-separated values, if you want to expand the details of multiple properties. For example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=workItems,iterations&api-version=6.0
```

To view details about the parameter '**`detailsToInclude`**', you can see '[**ResultDetails**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#resultdetails)'.

Comment: Ran, thanks for the response. Its not that I haven't gotten a response, it's that it's very inconsistent. Example this test failure has about 22 bugs as it's a data driven test with 100+ results.

![Bug Association in Azure DevOps](https://www.flickr.com/photos/192689328@N03/51096793646/)

The response I get is only one bug. 
![Response from REST API](https://www.flickr.com/photos/192689328@N03/51096821851/)

Comment: Any idea what that's happening? In previous instances the bug was entered for a different build and so the bugs didn't show up, so I walked back the builds list to find the bug. That's not in this case.

Comment: Hi @loganwol, Please try this API '`GET https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testresults/runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}/bugs?api-version=5.2-preview.1`'. I have tested it, it also can list all the associated bugs linked to test result.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bright. I tried the api above and still do not see the results I expect. It worked for cases where there was one bug but a test that has about 10. 

Including screenshots of what I see in ADO and what I see in Postman for the same runid and testcase result id.

[Bugs list in Azure DevOps](https://www.flickr.com/photos/192689328@N03/51099630535/), 
[Postman query](https://www.flickr.com/photos/192689328@N03/51098823746/)

Comment: Hi @loganwol, can you check if the '`testCaseResultId`' is right. Make sure it is not point to another test case result, neither the parent test case result nor the sub test case result.

Comment: As you see in the screenshots I included, in both cases the runid = 1136972 & testcase result id = 100004.

Comment: Hi @loganwol, You also can try this API "`GET https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testresults/runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}/workitems?api-version=6.1-preview.2`". You can get this API from the browser's web console logs (press F12, and go to **Nwtwork** tab) when you open the **Summary** page of a test result on the browser. This API is used to list all the linked work items on the test result. I have tried this API on Postman, and it also can work fine.

Comment: I tried the above API and I get nothing count 0 response.